# Can't Connect Multiple TCP POP3 clients with server

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, pop3

I keep getting this error while connecting 2nd TCP POP3 client with the server.
1st client connects without any error.I am connecting multiple clients with the help of List<>.

ERROR: System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Please help!

TcpPop3Client side code:

```
TcpClient _pop3Client1 = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1",110);
_pop3Client.Add(_pop3Client1);
_pop3Ns.Add(new NetworkStream());
_pop3Sw.Add(new StreamWriter());
_pop3Sr.Add(new StreamReader());

_pop3Ns[i] = _pop3Client.GetStream();
_pop3Sw[i] = new StreamWriter(_pop3Ns[i]);
_pop3Sr[i] = new StreamReader(_pop3Ns[i]);

string lines = pop3Response(_pop3Client, i) + "\n\n";
```

serverResponse code:

```
int ret = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[_pop3Client.ReceiveBufferSize];
ret = _pop3Ns[i].Read(data, 0, data.Length);

MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).ToString());
```

Comment: Why are you doing this: `_pop3Ns.Add(new NetworkStream());` and this: `_pop3Ns[i] = _pop3Client.GetStream();`? You're allocating memory for class instances that you never use. Just add the streams directly: `_pop3Ns.Add(_pop3Client.GetStream());` -- **This applies to your `StreamWriter/-Reader` too.**

Comment: Also where does the error occur?

Comment: thanks error resolved. my server is unable to initialize multiple pop3 clients simultanously.